# Water Volume Fill and Drain

Tags: volume

I have a pump that will (according to the instructions) pump $450$ litres of water per minute.

Water is pumped into a box that can hold $85$ litres. This box has $3 \times 1.5$ inch holes in a row on one side, near the bottom of the box. One on the left. One in the center, and one on the right. :)

I'm trying to solve a problem of the box overflowing after so many minutes/seconds of the pump being switched on. Due to this, the pump then needs to be switched off again for a few minutes to allow the box to drain slightly, before resuming.

> **Question:** What size box do I need, in order to handle this amount of water? Preventing the need of switching the pump off after so long?

Comment: This seems to be a physics problem more than a math problem. In reality, the rate at which the box drains will depend on how deep the water is. There are formulas to estimate that rate, though to really estimate the flow accurately you might need to do some relatively difficult calculation (taking viscosity into account, for example). In any case, it's not just the total size of the box, but the _shape_ of the box, that will determine whether you need to switch the pump off from time to time. An empirical answer is, try _taller_ boxes until you find one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to be unnecessary to stop the pump, the flow out of the box must be greater than or equal to the flow into the box. And the flow out of the box depends to a large degree on the height of the water.

To a first approximation we can use [Torricelli's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) where we find that the speed of water flowing out of a hole in a container is given by $$v = \sqrt{2gh}$$

where $v$ is speed, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration near the Earth's surface and $h$ is the height of the water above the hole. The flow out of the container $Q_{out}$ is then $$Q_{out}=Av$$

where $A$ is the area of the hole, or holes in this case. The flow into the container $Q_{in}$ is given. Setting $Q_{out}=Q_{in}$ and solving for $h$ we find $$Q_{out}=Q_{in}$$

$$=> \; A\sqrt{2gh}=Q_{in}$$
$$=> \; \sqrt{h}=\frac{Q_{in}}{A\sqrt{2g}}$$
$$=> \; h=\frac{Q_{in}^2}{2gA^2}$$

Plugging in the numbers, with $Q_{in}= 0.0075 \; \frac{m^3}{s}$, $g=9.81 \;\frac{m}{s^2}$ and $A=0.00342 \; m^2$, we find $$h=0.245 \; m$$

To a first approximation, your box should have at least this height above the holes. In reality, I would suggest multiplying this by a safety factor of at least $2$ as the flow through a hole [depends a lot](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/flow-liquid-water-tank-d_1753.html) on the shape and smoothness of the hole.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. So I'm thinking of getting a bin and putting 3 holes at the bottom. Would a 80-85 litre bin work better than a 85 litre box due to the extra height? I maybe able to get a big capacity, but 80-85 litres are the most common.

Comment: The higher the container, the better. The capacity isn't so important except as a means of dampening the splash and turbulence. Just make sure the water can flow freely out of the holes, i.e. that there is no buildup of back pressure. Good luck on your project.